# Map Discriminator Column to class Property Entity Framework Core 2.2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am failing to generate Migration for Entity Framework Core (v. 2.2.0)

I have a class "Question" which is inherited by class "MultipleChoiceQuestion" & "MatchColumns". I am trying to build a TPH (Table per Hierarchy) inheritance using Entity Framework Core. My base class (Question) has a property "QuestionType" to distinguish between child classes. The "QuestionType" property is an Enum. I don't want EF to generate a Discriminator column but use the property "QuestionType" as Discriminator column.

To create a proper migration, I am using the following code in dbcontext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>(b => b.HasDiscriminator(x => x.QuestionType).HasValue<MultipleChoiceQuestion>(QuestionType.MultipleChoiceQuestion).HasValue<MatchColumns>(QuestionType.MatchColumns));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().Property(p => p.QuestionType).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnName("QuestionType");
}
```

But when I run "Add-Migration" I get the following error:

> The entity type 'Question' is part of a hierarchy, but does not have a discriminator value configured.

Can't figure out why the configuring code is failing. I looked at the following documentation from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#discriminator-configuration

Any pointers why the configuration is incomplete/breaking?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `Question` should be abstract. Or it should be one of the possible record types, with a discriminator value.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Marking "Question" as abstract  creates migration but it now breaks model binding on HTTP Post as class is Abstract. Any other work-around?

Comment: Firstly you shouldn't bind data entities via MVC, that's what view models are for. MVC's default binders require knowing the concrete type of every property at compile time. You can only tell MVC to create an instance of `MultipleChoiceQuestion` by binding to a variable of type `MultipleChoiceQuestion`.

Comment: In fact, I am actually using a view model. I am trying to create a question paper which alllows Teacher to select questions from a mix list of questions (containing both Multiple choice as well as MatchColums). When the list of questions are posted, the controller takes a view model object which in turn contains a List of abstract question class object.

Comment: Well, you'll have to change the controller to accept something more specific. eg a `List<QuestionWrapper>` like `public class QuestionWrapper{ public MultipleChoiceQuestion Multi {get; set;} public MatchColumns Match {get;set;}}`